# Pagination in objective-c UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, pagination

I'm Trying to make pagination with this code.But When I scroll bottom its going 50-60 pages.
What I'm doing wrong.

```
NSInteger pagesNumber = 1;
    - (void)api {
    AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
    [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];


    NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.com/api/index.php"];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"process":@"search_customer",@"page": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",pagesNumber]};

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

    [manager setSecurityPolicy:securityPolicy];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager POST:urlPath parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *jsonData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

        self.customerCards = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSArray *customersArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"musteri_list"];


        for (NSDictionary *customersDictionary in customersArray) {
            ApiClass *customer = [ApiClass customersWithTitle:[customersDictionary objectForKey:@"adi"]];
            customer.tel = [customersDictionary objectForKey:@"tel"];



            NSLog(@"%@",customer.tel);

            [self.customerCards addObject:customer];

        }


        [self.tableView reloadData];

        NSLog(@"GET: %@", string);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

And This is my scrollViewDidScroll method.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView_ {
    if(self.tableView.contentOffset.y >= (self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height))
    {
        pagesNumber = pagesNumber + 1;
        [self api];
    }
}
```

So I what should I do in this section.And When I scroll Up data is missing.Its showing currentPageData.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declaration:
NSInteger pagesNumber = 1;

Call "api" method from viewDidLoad, to load data:

    - (void)api {
        AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
        [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];


        NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.com/api/index.php"];
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

        NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"process":@"search_customer",@"page": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",pagesNumber]};

        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

        [manager setSecurityPolicy:securityPolicy];
        manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
        [manager POST:urlPath parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSData *jsonData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

            self.customerCards = [NSMutableArray array];
            NSArray *customersArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"musteri_list"];


            for (NSDictionary *customersDictionary in customersArray) {
                ApiClass *customer = [ApiClass customersWithTitle:[customersDictionary objectForKey:@"adi"]];
                customer.tel = [customersDictionary objectForKey:@"tel"];



                NSLog(@"%@",customer.tel);

                [self.customerCards addObject:customer];

            }

            [self.tableView reloadData];

            NSLog(@"GET: %@", string);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
    }

//instead of using scrollViewDidScroll better use willDisplayCell:

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        if(self.customerCards.count>1){
            if(indexPath.row == self.customerCards.count-1){
pagesNumber=pagesNumber+1;

                [self api];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I called api in viewdidLoad before.I changed the code to willDisplayCell but its not increasing pagesNumbers.

Comment: have you done this when you received your api response pagesNumber=self.customerCards.count;

Comment: It's just giving me customerCards.Count and its 30.So pagesNumber = 30;
But its have to increase when I scroll bottom.

Comment: okay thats fine. After [self.tableView reloadData] this the table row count is 30. When you scroll till the bottom, willDisplayCell trigger this will again call api method having pagesNumber=30. is it so? plz check

Comment: at the bottom side do you need to load pagesNumber=2 data. i'm thinking right?

Comment: Okay then remove pagesNumber=self.customerCards.count; //store customerCards count inside pagesNumber this line of code and add pagesNumber = pagesNumber + 1; inside willDisplayCell: before you call api method.